# Android Media Router no discovered devices

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am currently playing around with Androids Media Playback API. After following the developer guide from [Android Developers | Media Router](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html#media-routes) I got stuck at the point of discovering available Media Routes and so making the cast button in the action bar visible.

I have a TV set next to me, which can be used to play media playback and is also discovered by other apps like YouTube or BubbleUPnP.

Sadly Logcat just logs the addition and selection of my own device route.

Am I missing something or doing it wrong? I am trying to avoid the usage of the chrome cast sdk - to keep it as simple as possible for now. I also made sure that I am only using imports from the media router support library.

Currently I am using a single activity extending ActionBarActivity.

```
...
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaControlIntent;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter;
...

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private MediaRouter mediaRouter;
    private MediaRouteSelector selector;
    private MediaRouter.Callback mediaRouterCallback =
        new MediaRouter.Callback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onRouteAdded(
                MediaRouter router,
                MediaRouter.RouteInfo route)
            {
                Log.d("MediaRouterCallback", "added route: " + route);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRouteSelected(
                MediaRouter router,
                MediaRouter.RouteInfo route)
            {
                Log.d("MediaRouterCallback", "selected route: " + route);
            }
        };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(this);
        selector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder().
            addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO).
            addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_VIDEO).
            addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK).
            build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        mediaRouter.addCallback(
            selector,
            mediaRouterCallback,
            MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);

        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
        mediaRouter.removeCallback(mediaRouterCallback);

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem mediaRouteItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cast_media);

        MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider =
            (MediaRouteActionProvider)MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(
                mediaRouteItem);
        mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(selector);

        return true;
    }
}
```

The cast button comes from my resource file menu_main.

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cast_media"
        android:title="@string/action_cast_media"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```